# In grid layout poistioning node in a specific cell

Tags: grid-layout, cytoscape.js

I am  also trying to positioning a node in a cell in grid layout as below

```
layout: { name: 'grid', 
  fit: true, // whether to fit the viewport to the graph 
  rows:5, 
  columns:12, 
  padding: 10, // the padding on fit 
  position: function( node )
     { console.log("Row : "+node.data('row') + ", COL : "+node.data('col')); 
        return {row:3, col:node.data('col')}; 
     } 
 },
```

But node is always created in the middle of the canvas, even if I hardcode the row as above. Any suggestion, what is going on. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're manually specifying positions, you shouldn't need to set the overall dimensions.  Maybe you've overconstrained it (e.g. row beyond rows)?

Alternatively, you could set the dimensions and a sort function to indicate the ordering.

Comment: I did not get what do you mean by overall dimensions. Here is what I also tried:
layout: {
                     name: 'grid',
                      fit: true, 
                      padding: 5, 
                      position: function( node ){ 
               console.log("Row : " + node.data('row') + ", COL : " +node.data('col')); 
               return {row:2, col:3}; 
              }                                     
                  }
with no luck

Comment: my requirement is to change the layout as I add node. so if I have one node I want that to be in first row and col and if I have two that should go in 3rd row and in 1st column. 
third node should go in 2nd row and 2 column etc. I did not find good example to do that either

Comment: Running without `rows` and `columns` works if `position` is specified.  You can rerun grid with animations, or maybe Cola is better suited.  You'll have to experiment for your usecase.